# getting a pointer to struct inside a map

Tags: c++

I am trying to convert the following `o1` to `r1`:

```
map<int, vector<vector<myStruct>>> o1;
map<int, vector<vector<myStruct*>>> r1;

for(int i = 0; i < o1.size(); ++i)
{
    auto element = o1[i];
    vector<vector<myStruct*> tmp;
    for(int j = 0; j < element.size(); ++j)
    {
        tmp.push_back({});
        for(int k = 0; k < element[j].size(); ++k)
        {
            tmp[j].push_back(&element[j][k]);
        }
    }
    r1[i] = tmp;
}
```

However I notice that at the end of the loop, `element` does not exist in `r1` anymore. How do I write it such that the pointer to the `element` still exists inside `r1`?

Comment: This is not the right way to iterate over map, use iterators or range-based loop

Comment: This code has mismatched `< >`

Answer (score 1):

It is better to do it using standard algorithm `std::transform` and doing it step by step:

First we convert `std::vector<myStruct>` to `std::vector<myStruct*>`:

```
auto cnv_v = []( std::vector<myStruct> &v ) {
    std::vector<myStruct*> r;
    std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter( r ),
        []( myStruct &ms ) { return std::adressof( ms ); }
    );
    return r;
};
```

now we can convert vector of vector:

```
auto cnv_vv = []( std::vector<std::vector<myStruct>> &v ) {
    std::vector<std::vector<myStruct*>> r;
    std::transform( v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter( r ),
        cnv_v );
    );
    return r;
};
```

and putting it all together to convert `std::map`:

```
std::transform( o1.begin(), o1.end(), std::inserter( r1 ),
     []( auto &p ) { return std::make_pair( p.first, cnv_vv( p.second ) ); } );
```